# Access violation

Tags: c, pointers

When i debug my c project in Visual Studio I got this output:

```
'SR.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'SR.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'SR.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'SR.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x00171d63 in SR.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
Unhandled exception at 0x00171d63 in SR.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.
```

What causes the problem?

Comment: You're accessing memory which you shouldn't. Most probably through an uninitialized pointer...

Comment: You're using an uninitialised pointer in your code.  Build a debug version of your project and run it under the debugger to investigate

Comment: Run your program in the debugger. It will help you locate where the crash happens, as well as let you examine variables to help you figure out what might have caused it.

Answer (score 1):

You try to read something at the address `0xcccccccc` and this address is not a valid memory address.

Probably a pointer badly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on "Break when an exception is thrown" in Visual Studio. Quick Key: Ctrl-Alt-E and select Native Run Time Checks and C++ exceptions.  Re-debug, and it should stop on the errant code.